# Union of closed convex sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $(K_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of convex, compact sets in the space $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that

$$K_1\subsetneqq K_2\cdots \subsetneqq K_n\cdots.$$

Put $K=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n$. Assume that $K$ is bounded. Can we deduce that $K$ is always **not closed**?

This is true for $k=1$. It is also true if the sequence is such that $K_n$ is contained in the interior of $K_{n+1}$. Is it possible to prove this in the general case or is there a counterexample?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find this problem? Is this something you just came up with? Also, regarding the assumption of *convex*, is a counterexample known when one of the $K_i$ is **not** convex?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow: Let $K_n= [\overline{B}_1(0)\setminus B_{1/n}(0)]\cup \{ 0\}$

Comment: Or $K_n = B_{1 - 1/n} \cup S_1$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The claim is obviously true for $k=1$.
It is *not* true for $k\ge2$:

Define the sets
$$
S:= \{ x\in \mathbb R^k: \|x\|_2\le 1, \ x_1=0\},
$$
which is a closed, $k-1$-dimensional ball,
and
$$
B_n = \{x\in \mathbb R^k: \|x\|_2\le 1, \ x_k \le 1- \frac1n\},
$$
which is a ball that is cut.
Then
$$
K_n = conv(S \cup B_n)
$$
is an increasing sequence of convex and compact sets.
And its union $K=\cup K_n$ is the closed unit ball:

Let $\|x\|_2\le 1$. If $x_k=1$ then $x\in S \subset K_n$, if $x_k<1$ then $x\in B_n$ for all $n$ such that $1-\frac1n\ge x_k$, or equivalently for all $n$ with $n\ge \frac1{1-x_k}$.